# What exit code integer grep returns when it doesn't match a string?

Tags: grep, exit-status

What exit code integer grep returns when it doesn't match a string?

I know it returns 0 when it does match and I assume it returns 1 when it doesn't.

Is that correct?

Comment: You assume correctly.   man pages confirm, as does `grep --help 2>&1|grep Exit` which yields "Exit status is 0 if any line is selected, 1 otherwise;"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`man grep` helps:

```
EXIT STATUS
    The grep utility exits with one of the following values:

    0     One or more lines were selected.
    1     No lines were selected.
    >1    An error occurred.
```

Also, for [GNU Grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html):

```
However, if the -q or --quiet or --silent option is used and a line is
selected, the exit status is 0 even if an error occurred. Other grep 
implementations may exit with status greater than 2 on error.
```

And, depending on the implementation:

```
Normally, exit status is 0 if matches were found, and 1 if
no  matches  were found.  (The -v option inverts the sense
of the exit status.)
```

---

To test yourself, put the following in a script and run it.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Match: "
echo grep | grep grep >/dev/null; echo $?
echo -n "Inverted match (-v): "
echo grep | grep -v grep; echo $?
echo -n "Nonmatch: "
echo grep | grep grepx; echo $?
echo -n "Inverted nonmatch (-v): "
echo grep | grep -v grepx >/dev/null; echo $?
echo -n "Quiet match (-q): "
echo grep | grep -q grep; echo $?
echo -n "Quiet nonmatch (-q): "
echo grep | grep -q grepx; echo $?
echo -n "Inverted quiet match (-qv): "
echo grep | grep -qv grep; echo $?
echo -n "Inverted quiet nonmatch (-qv): "
echo grep | grep -qv grepx; echo $?
```